PowerBI slicer vs User Selection Interaction
I created a PowerBI Dashboard as part of a Job Simulation task and discovered a couple of weird behaviors of PowerBI desktop...
First is this,

For some reason, data in the table view is missing but shows up normally in the query editor.  Despite the missing values, the visualizations and measures worked normally so I didn't bother.
Then, I was finally done with the dashboard and checking if all the visuals are working properly only to find errors in two of them...

There is supposed to be a treemap in the bottom-right corner that appears to be empty and the 'Overall Calls Abandoned' card is supposed to show a number like shown in 'overall calls answered' card. Problem is, I have selected an agent (Becky) from the table and all other visuals are interacting to the selection except these two.
If were to add a slicer for selecting an agent, all the visuals interact the way they are supposed to. Check this...

Selecting an agent from the table should have given the same results but for some reason, it doesn't.
I checked the interactions of the all visuals here, all are set to interacting with each other (except the scatter plot, I need it to be constant).
This could be an issue with updates, I checked if my setup was up-to-date, all I got was a blocked 'Display Notification' check box.

Version Details were:  Version: 2.130.930.0 64-bit (June, 2024)
If you need a copy of the .pbix file, I'm gonna need help with how to upload one here.
There is also a good chance I'm making a silly mistake with the visuals so special thanks for the help if that is the case...
